# Working Excel ArrayFormula to be split into VBA because too long

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

I am struggling trying to let an Excel Array formula to be applied through a VBA code.

The formula is the following:

```
=IF(B2=VLOOKUP(B2,Admin!$G$5:$G$501,1,FALSE),IFERROR(INDEX(Admin!$G$5:$K$501,MATCH(1,(Admin!$I$5:$I$501=A2)*(Admin!$G$5:$G$501=B2),0),5),INDEX(Admin!$G$5:$K$501,MATCH(1,(Admin!$I$5:$I$501="ALL")*(Admin!$G$5:$G$501=B2),0),5)),"")
```

I am trying to apply it through VBA using the following code:

```
Sub LongArrayformula()
  Dim ArrayFormulaPart1, ArrayFormulaPart2 As String
  ArrayFormulaPart1 = "=IF(B2=VLOOKUP(B2,Admin!$G$5:$G$501,1,FALSE),IFERROR(INDEX(Admin!$G$5:$K$501,XXXX"
  ArrayFormulaPart2 = "MATCH(1,(Admin!$I$5:$I$501=A2)*(Admin!$G$5:$G$501=B2),0),5),INDEX(Admin!$G$5:$K$501,MATCH(1,(Admin!$I$5:$I$501=""ALL"")*(Admin!$G$5:$G$501=B2),0),5)),"""")"
     With ActiveSheet.Range("bv2")
         .FormulaArray = ArrayFormulaPart1
         .Replace "XXXX", ArrayFormulaPart2, lookat:=xlPart

        End With
End Sub
```

I know on the web there are many sites covering this subject but I can't let this formula be applied automatically.

I keep getting the error "Unable to set the FormulaArray propoerty of the Range class" and the ".FormulaArray = ArrayFormulaPart1" gets highlighted.

I have tried other codes as well with no luck. Since the syntax is pretty much unknown to me, I am not sure about what to change in order to adapt the many codes I sow to my needs.

Thank you in advance for your help and eventually a quick explanation on how to properly set an array formula using VBA.

Comment: Also, Just remember to accept the answers that you use.  In your last question you acknowledge that the answer works but did not accept it.  you do that by clicking the check mark by the answer that you used.  If you do not give that type of feedback others will stop answering your future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the first formula must be a viable formula to be entered in the first place:

```
Sub LongArrayformula()
    Dim ArrayFormulaPart1, ArrayFormulaPart2 As String
    ArrayFormulaPart1 = "=IF(B2=VLOOKUP(B2,Admin!$G$5:$G$501,1,FALSE),IFERROR(INDEX(Admin!$G$5:$K$501,9999,5),INDEX(Admin!$G$5:$K$501,MATCH(1,(Admin!$I$5:$I$501=""ALL"")*(Admin!$G$5:$G$501=B2),0),5)),"""")"
    ArrayFormulaPart2 = "MATCH(1,(Admin!$I$5:$I$501=A2)*(Admin!$G$5:$G$501=B2),0)"
    With ActiveSheet.Range("bv2")
        .FormulaArray = ArrayFormulaPart1
        .Replace "9999", ArrayFormulaPart2, lookat:=xlPart
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Scott, Thank you. It worked.
I have read that you had to split the formula somewhere but all the examples I have seen were breaking the formula always at the end. I have never thought you could actually "break" the formula anywhere. One last question for you if you can answer: the "lookat:=XlPart" what does it do? and why some codes do not have it while others do (at least this is what I have found on the web)?

Thanks again for your precious and fast help

Comment: @fedone see my comment above about what you should do with answers.  You cannot select correct till the question is 15 minutes old, but you can go back and select the correct answer on your last question.